# Custom column validation formula for ensuring every item is selected in a choice question

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, validation

I have a choice column (`Required Checks`) with `CheckA`, `CheckB`, and `CheckC` as options; multiple options is turned on.

I have another choice column (`Verdict`) with `Approved` and `Denied`. (and other options, but we are keeping this simple).

I would like to only allow the `Approved` choice in the `Verdict` column... IF everything in the `Required Checks` are selected.  In other words, they can only select `Approved` in the `Verdict` column if they have already selected `CheckA`, `CheckB`, and `CheckC` in the "Required Checks" column.

Optionally, I'd love to just give them a warning, but still let them select `Approved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your requirements can't be achieved using column validation.

Please check this article: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/

> The Choice field with Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) is not
>   allowed in the SharePoint Validation Settings and the Calculated
>   field.